# How to using intents to view calendar data?

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

I made this code:

```
long eventID = 208;
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, eventID);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
   .setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

I made sure the EventID was correct, and the event-title showed in the view was correct.

THE PROBLEM is the event time was incorrect, like: 1970-1-1 8:00.

Why? Anyone can Help? Thanks.

Comment: try querying the calendar database, this may give some insight into why it has that.

Comment: have try query, but the data of time is correct.

Comment: Could you post the code of how you're reading the calendar's content?

Comment: too long. the code like this below:
1st, query the DB, fetch the eventID.
2nd, use the API(the code before) to open the intent, but the intent view showed the wrong Event time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the event begin & end time to intent's extra data :

```
intent.putExtra("beginTime", beginMilliTS);
intent.putExtra("endTime", endMilliTS);
```

I got this working by using the values from "begin" and "end" field of an event instance.
This should work too with "dtstart" and "dtend" field from an event.

Comment: +1 for this great answer. However, this code seems to crash when trying to view events that are recurring. Do you know of a way to get around this?

Comment: Never see a crash. To edit a reccuring event, you have to get real events associated to it. Use the instance DB, not the event DB; then use the event_id, begin, end (these are the field's name in instance DB) to setup the intent.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. If you'd like, submit your answer here and I'll accept it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532549/android-calendar-recurring-events-have-wrong-end-date-time

Comment: Nice one. This also solved my problem with freezing of the app on HTC Sense when trying to view event detail. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may help you!!!
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

Answer (score 1):

on Android 4.2.2, seems still having the same problem. Is it the correct behavior, or some thing missing here?

1. got the event id through Instances.query(Globals.sContext.getContentResolver(), proj, begin, end); proj= String[]{Instances.EVENT_ID, Instances.BEGIN, Instances.END...};
2. use the even id to view the event in calendar app.

tried with code (from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html), it still shows December 31 1969 on the 'Detail view' opened by the 'intent'; and shows current date in the 'Edit event' form if clicking on the the event on the 'Detail view' of the calendar.

...

```
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, eventID);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

   .setData(uri);

startActivity(intent);
```

and still does not work even with the:

```
intent.putExtra("beginTime", from);
intent.putExtra("endTime", till);  //'from', 'till' is the mills got from the Instances.BEGIN/END fields from the query
```

EDIT:
the following code works. only difference is using the define `CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME`

```
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, eventId);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri);
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, from);
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, till);
startActivity(intent);
```