# Calendar showing older date For Event?

Tags: android, calendar

I am developing an android application in which i need to give some features of calendar like adding events and displaying events ,
There is no problem in insertion for that i am using the following code

```
              Date date = new Date();
        
        System.out.println("dateselected is    " + dateselected);
        try {
 
            date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dateselected);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        startTime = date.getTime();
        
        System.out.println("startTime is    " + startTime);
                
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();       
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);  
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra(" THE TESTING EVENT ");
        intent.putExtra("beginTime", startTime);
        
        intent.putExtra("endTime", startTime+60*60*1000);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        finish();
        startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

Displaying event in this way

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events/" + 
                 
                    String.valueOf(eventid[pos])));
            
            System.out.println(" >8 "); 
            //Android 2.1 and below.
            //intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://calendar/events/" + String.valueOf(calendarEventID)));    
        
            
            startActivity(intent);
```

but the problem is that no matter which date i selected and whatever the event id is
it shows only one date and time ,

**`5:30 am , 1 January 1970`**

though the event title is correct

**which i am testing on samsung galaxy pop android 2.2.1**

What should i do to remove this error

Comment: Where does dateselected come from?

Comment: it comes from previous activity  which i receive like dateselected = getIntent().getStringExtra("date"); and is like  "DATE  IS HERE CHECK = " 2012-05-16

Comment: It's weird, because 1 Jaunary 1970 is the date by defalut when you do a new Date(). It seems that maybe SimpleDateFormat is not working properly. Have you check with the debugger  the value of dateselect before calling parse method and the value of date after?

Comment: @gutiory dateselect has got the right date i printed that in logcat and , when i insert the event in calendar the start date and end date of the event in calendar is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have got the solution for this question , from here

[How to using intents to view calendar data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798997/how-to-using-intents-to-view-calendar-data)

and used the following code
just passed the extra intent to display the calendar events with the selected date.

```
intent.putExtra("beginTime", beginMilliTS);
intent.putExtra("endTime", endMilliTS);
```