# How can I open a Calendar to a specified date with no EventID?

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

I would like to be able to open the user's default calendar on a specified date that might not have an Event ID, with the intended purpose of having him view the his calendar to see if there is no appointments etc. Is this at all possible? I'm currently using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798997/how-to-using-intents-to-view-calendar-data) as a guide. But it obviously needs some event ID.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I found [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-view) in googles Calendar Provider API

The gist of the code boils down to this.

```
    long startMillis;
...
Uri.Builder builder = CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
builder.appendPath("time");
ContentUris.appendId(builder, startMillis);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setData(builder.build());
startActivity(intent);
```